# Знак препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, бсп

Какой знак ставится в БСП, если оно синонимично сложносочинённому предложению с союзом а не то и СПП с придаточным причины?
Например:

**А ты не злись колючкой станешь**

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в этом случае, ставится тире, так как во второй части предложения имеется значение следствия или результата, следующего из первой части.

```
А ты не злись - колючкой станешь
```